# Double cone with countably many cones instead of two

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, reference-works

Is there a notion of a singularity of a real "algebraic variety" which looks locally like a [double cone](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleCone.html) but with a countable infinite number of cones which meet in the same point? A short example or reference would be highly appreciated.

I am self-studying algebraic geometry at the moment and the literature/videos do not treat this topic and I am lacking the necessary intuition.

Comment: The answer depends on what your definitions are. Unless you're willing to discard some fairly standard finiteness hypotheses, the answer is no (i.e. nothing that can locally be embedded in $\Bbb R^n$ can satisfy this). Could you provide a little more clarification about what your definitions are and what you're hoping to do with this infinite union of cones?

Comment: For a singularity or singular point I use the definition from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_point_of_an_algebraic_variety in the sense that you cannot assign a "good" tangent space and an real algebraic variety is the set of zeros of some set of polynomials. I put "algebraic variety" in quotation marks since it seems logical that the number of "cones" being attached to the singular point depends on the degree of the set of polynomials and in the countable infinite case, this does not work.

Comment: It is a construction, which comes from a dynamical model and it represents the possibilities to come back to some "special" set (which is reduced to this singular point) when moving through $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: Sorry, the definitions I was asking about are your definitions for "algebraic variety". It sounds like you are requiring that your object be embeddable in $\Bbb R^n$. Is this the case? If so, the answer to your question is no and I would be happy to write an answer once you confirm that.

Comment: Indeed, it should be embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^n$. But if the property could be in some more general sense be obtainable, I would be happy to hear about it too...

Comment: May I kindly ask you to elaborate on the problem regarding the embedding in $\mathbb{R}^n$? For $n=2$ I imagined you start with a finite number $k$ of cones,  with angle $\frac{\pi}{k}$ each, and order them uniformly around the origin $p=0$. Then, put in each of the $k$ holes again $k$ cones with angle $\frac{\pi}{2k}$ and so on. This way the cones become very tight very fast but it seems like an embedding for the case of a family of 2 dimensional cones in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Could you please explain what I fail to see here?

Comment: It can't be cut out by polynomials. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any set in $\Bbb R^n$ cut out by polynomial equations $f_1,\cdots,f_m$ has some strong finiteness properties: the number of irreducible components must be finite, as these correspond to minimal prime ideals of the ring $\Bbb R[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/\sqrt[\Bbb R]{(f_1,\cdots,f_m)}$, which is noetherian (being a quotient of the noetherian ring $\Bbb R[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$) and hence has finitely many minimal prime ideals. So infinitely many cones meeting at a point in $\Bbb R^n$ cannot be cut out by polynomial equations.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have a literature suggestion on this topic precisely?

Comment: What do you mean, "this topic"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the statement "the number of irreducible components must be finite,..." because this does probably not apply to the ring of continuous functions.

Comment: Yes, because that's not a noetherian ring. As I said in the post, irreducible components of an algebraic set correspond to minimal primes of the coordinate ring - this is the nullstellensatz, basically. (You may need the positivstellensatz whne working over $\Bbb R$, but it's same idea - there's a bijection between closed algebraic subsets and certain ideals of the coordinate ring, and then you can use some basic ring theory on the coordinate ring to conclude.) Intro algebraic geometry and commutative algebra books are probably relevant for some of this, but wouldn't treat cont. functions.

Answer (score 1):

A [semialgebraic set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semialgebraic_set) has finitely many connected components.

Assume you have  $X$ semialgebraic with such a conic point, then $(X\cap B) \backslash\{P\}$ would be still semialgebraic, and have infinitely many components, contradiction.

[Real algebraic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_algebraic_geometry) studies such sets.